# iOS App Submission Cheat Sheet

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there a "Cheat sheet" for submitting an iOS app to the App Store

App is tested and ready for submission

Distribution provisioning profile is created and downloaded
When attempting to add the distribution provisioning profile to the Library > Provisioning profiles - I get a "Valid signing identity not found"

I have spent a whole day going thru  fragmented pieces of information but there seems to be no information that would outline the whole workflow - does apple make it this difficult for a reason.?

Comment: What?  Provisioning isn't difficult, and Apple has made the process more streamlined if anything.  (e.g. The android market is a nightmare)

Comment: Well I hoping that there is a wizard somewhere (that I don't know of)  that will walk me through the process.

Comment: Post your build settings for the "Release" configuration (assuming you are using the standard "Archive" and "Validate"/"Submit" methods.)  It would also be helpful for you to specify which Xcode release you are using (I'm assuming 4.3.x).

Comment: It has been hypothesized that being able to find, read and understand all the documentation regarding the iOS workflow is Apple's Turing test for a developer being competent enough to submit an app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this two parts series tutorial "How to submit your app to Apple".

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Edit: 2nd part of the tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

Comment: This link was extremely helpful.  It helped me create my distribution profile but it left off where I needed it the most - i.e. how to prepare your app for distribution.  I could not find the part 2 of this post.

Comment: I added the link to the 2nd part of the tutorial.

Comment: This was extremely helpful - muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite a workflow, but it's the most comprehensive list I know of things to check pre-submission: https://ontestpad.com/library/201/ios-app-store-submission-checklist

It's by no means a step-by-step walkthrough, but if you can answer yes to every item and still have issues submitting, I'll be surprised.

Comment: Yes this is quite useful but is more of a checklist of what to make sure of prior to submission.  I am looking for how to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the various online list to help check if you've forgotten anything, nothing beats reading all of Apple's documentation, all of it, including documentation in the iOS Developer Center, iOS Provisioning Portal and iTunes Connect, plus your Standard Developer agreement.  Apple's documentation is their latest word, which changes from time-to-time, and includes tons of details not on all of the summary lists, stuff that could potentially get you into trouble if you don't understand all of these details.

Keeping up with the various iPhone/iOS developer forums on the various mistakes that developers occasionally make, and on interesting new or unexpected reasons for app rejections, also helps.

Comment: Keeping up with the forums looks like a good idea, but seems to suck all the time out of my day. Have you got a a particular forum that's uber-useful?